# factory_girl - how to create an object within the definition of another object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot, rspec-rails

I have adopted a Rails app and am trying to put some model tests in; I am using FactoryGirl for the first time so this might be a beginner question.

There is a model called object_connection that links together two pieces of information. It works fine in development but it relates to a food_item and a drink_item but doesn't have an association. The problem is that every time I run a spec those two create's get run. I'd like to get a simple factory to create this but the following doesn't work:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :test_object_connection, class: ObjectConnection do
    m=FactoryGirl.create :menu_item
    fi=FactoryGirl.create(:test_food_item, menu_header_id: 1, menu_id: 1)
    food_id fi.id
    food_location_id fi.location_id
    drink_id m.id
  end
end
```

I tried doing a before(:create) but it didn't seem to be working. I know ideally there should be an association but I would rather just get this test working correctly and then propose those changes. What would be the proper way to create local variables in the creation of a factory?

thx

Comment: I suppose `food`, `food_location` and `drink` are `belongs_to` association in ObjectConnection. Am I right?

Comment: I wish :-) Nat at this point. They are managed manually and looking to model via associations. One issue is that food and drink are derived from same table. Thinking best way to do this as it's currently an either / or for two items but might be more in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is the right way, but worked for me (via TestFoodItem.last.location_id).

FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :test_object_connection, class: ObjectConnection do

```
food_id          { FactoryGirl.create(:test_food_item, menu_header_id: 1, menu_id: 1).id }

food_location_id { TestFoodItem.last.location_id }

drink_id         { FactoryGirl.create(:menu_item).id }
```

end
end